# DB2 Insert and Deadlocks

Tags: db2, deadlock, insert

My application has 4 different threads doing inserts into the same DB2 table simultaneously.

Could this cause a deadlock / lockwait situtation?

Theoretically I don't see a problem here; as one insert statement is not going to lock a row required by another insert statement because all are independent insert statements.

Also, I commit after each insert so transaction log wouldn't fill up.

I'm looking for a high performance model while avoiding any potential lock situtation. Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Is this at all related to your other question? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47652/db2-communication-link-failure-issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem either.

If your application logic allows, you might consider committing every N rows.

For improved performance, you might consider whether you can do blocked inserts of multiple rows at a time.

(I use DB2 for i. If you are on LUW or z/OS, your mileage may vary.)